# Converting Malware Code or Benign Code to Gray Scale

Tags: image, assembly, grayscale

How to convert Binary code to Gray Scale Image?

Recently I've been seeing Malware is converted to Image.
**Malware Binary -> 8 bit Vector -> Gray-Scale Image.**
I've less knowledge on this Image Conversion. How to do this?

Comment: Are you talking about just using the machine-code bytes as pixel data?  (That would be trivial, e.g. with a [`.pgm` binary (P5) header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm_format) followed by the binary data, or probably similar with a BMP header).  Can you show or at least link and describe an example of what you're talking about?

Comment: https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?doid=2016904.2016908

Comment: https://vizsec.org/files/2011/Nataraj.pdf
This is better if you didn't have access to ACM. This explained well.

Comment: Ok yeah, all-zeros turns into a fully black area, so they are just stuffing the bytes into a BMP or PGM as greyscale data.  The slide even has as suggested image width parameter, which is really the only choice to make if you're not doing any pre-processing of the data.  Go read about the PGM image format; it's *extremely* simple, and pretty trivial to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the slides you linked, it looks like **they're literally just treating the bytes of the executable *as grayscale image data*, one byte per pixel, with black=0.**

For smaller files, they use a narrower width (e.g. 32 pixels wide), or a larger width for large files, so you always get a tall image.

This is trivial to do, e.g. with the [PGM-binary (`P5`) image format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm_format) which has a very short and simple text header and then the binary data.  The header does have to specify a height as well, so you have to calculate that from the chosen width and file size.

e.g. this quick hack of a shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# args: filename  [width]
# writes to stdout, redirect to a file

fn=$1
width=${2:-32}   # default width=32 if there's no 2nd arg

size=$(stat -c %s "$fn")
echo -e "P5\n$width $((size/width))\n255"   # header
cat "$fn"
```

The output on a 15kiB `a.out` made by gcc is this, which I can view (and scale up) with any image viewer that understands PNG images.  e.g. `qiv`, `geeqie`, `gwenview`.

```
P5              (grayscale, binary version)
32 449          (width height)
255             (max grayscale value)
^?ELF^B^A^A...
```

e.g. `./stick-in-pgm.sh a.out 64 > a.out.64.pgm` correctly uses width=64 and calculates height=224 from the file size.

Apparently most PGM-reading programs don't care if the exact file size is a full number of lines, but they do complain that the file "ends early" if the height is too large.  (So you can't just `echo 32 10000`.)  Dividing the size by the width gives a height that gets them to not complain; I didn't need to use `dd` to pad the output to a full number of 32-byte "row" blocks.